# SQLite: retrieving rows with similar values

Tags: sql, sqlite

given the following table:

```
+------------+----------+
|  id        |  value   |
+------------+----------+
| 1          | 10       |
| 1          | 20       |
| 1          | 30       |
| 2          | 10       |
| 2          | 30       |
| 2          | 40       |
| 3          | 10       |
| 3          | 20       |
| 3          | 30       |
| 3          | 40       |
+------------+---------+
```

I want to find all id's who share at least 3 similar values and the average of these values (id1, id2, avg(value))

Thus the statement should return:

1,3,20

2,3,26.6

Can anybody give me a hint about which command I need (using SQLite)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to self join on the value and not equal IDs. Then group by the pair of IDs. Use `avg(value)` to get the average and `count(DISTINCT value)` in a `HAVING` clause to check for the minimum of three shared values.

```
SELECT t1.id,
       t2.id,
       avg(value)
       FROM elbat t1
            INNER JOIN elbat t2
                       ON t2.id <> t1.id
                          AND t2.value = t1.value
       GROUP BY t1.id,
                t2.id
       HAVING count(DISTINCT value) >= 3;
```

Or remove the `DISTINCT`, if it's also a match, when three values are shared but at least two of them are the same. And if you don't want the pairs of IDs to repeat (in reverse order), change `<>` to `<` or `>`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following SQL :

```
select id as "ID", count(id) as "Count", avg(value) as "Avg Value"
  from tab
 group by id
 order by id
```